# Remove XML declaration using msxml6/IXMLDOMDocument2

Tags: com, msxml6, ixmldomdocument

I want to remove XML declaration only from an XML using C++/COM-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

using the `IXMLDOMDocument2` interface of `msxml6`

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IXMLDocument::xml property and save the string to a file.

Comment: Thanks. CComBSTR bstrXml;  hr=pRootElement->get_xml(&bstrXml);